# open source Graph class for c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I'm going to write a framework for implementation of algorithms on graphs. Of course I have to write my own Graph class, but at first I want to see what good implementations of this kind of class are there exist. I only know about `boost::graph`. What other open source C++ libraies could you suggest to look at?

Comment: Why? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Because there is no such kind of class which definetely satisfies my requirements.

Comment: @Mihran: but the nice thing about Boost.Graph is that you can *customize* it to fit your requirements. And this works for pretty much *all* requirements. Boost.Graph is *incredibly* powerful and flexible.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039617/how-to-fit-a-custom-graph-to-the-boost-graph-library-template

Comment: I know all this feautures, but for my framework I need something more than simple graphs, and boost doesn't allows things I want :)

Comment: So what actually do you want to do what is not posible with Boost.Graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with `boost:graph`. It's a mature and high quality library, so I see no reasons why you should look further than that.

And using it + studying its source will help you more than if you fumble about trying to make your own graph class without taking a look at proven libraries.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it will be good to look at some other implementations.

Comment: `boost::graph` is excellent. You can even use it on graph structures you did not anticipate. I managed to use it to solve dynamic programming problems on arrays. You have to write iterator/traits classes which describe the graph structure, and use the `boost::graph` algorithms. They also provide a swiss-army-knife graph class suitable for most purposes, and also wrappers to legacy Fortran graph libraries.